# Timeline / Schedule in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, timeline

Is there a way to do a timeline / schedule in HighCharts that looks similar to this? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#an-advanced-example.

I found http://jsfiddle.net/VenomXLR/u3eWz/ which is close enough, but cannot see how to put labels in the body of the bar... eg

> ```
>       data: [{
>              label:'foo bar',
>              x: 0,
>              low: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 0, 0, 0),
>              high: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 4, 0, 0)
>          }
> ```

This http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/ is also close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable `dataLabels` and set [`inside`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.columnrange.dataLabels.inside) to `true` for them. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u3eWz/322/

```
plotOptions: {
  columnrange: {
    grouping: false,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      inside: true,
      format: '{point.series.name}'
    }
  }
},
```

Another option could be to try [Gantt chart](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart). It is being developed, but for your requirements should be working fine already.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o3woh3ye/

```js
var year = 365 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// THE CHART
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'gantt'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Gantt Chart'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: year * 5,
        labels: {
            format: '{value:%Y}',
            style: {
                fontSize: '15px'
            }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        maxPadding: 0.2
    }],
    yAxis: [{
        categories: ['President', 'Vice President', 'Secretary of State'],
        reversed: true,
        grid: true
    }],
    series: [{
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
         format: '{point.taskName}'
        },
        data: [{
            start: Date.UTC(1780,0,1),
            end: Date.UTC(1788,0,1),
            taskGroup: 0,
            taskName: 'George Washington'
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(1788,0,1),
            end: Date.UTC(1794,0,1),
            taskName: 'John Adams',
            taskGroup: 0
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(1770,0,1),
            end: Date.UTC(1780,0,1),
            taskName: 'John Adams',
            taskGroup: 1
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(1780,0,1),
            end: Date.UTC(1790,0,1),
            taskName: 'Name Name',
            taskGroup: 2
        }]
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/gantt.src.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. That works perfectly. Thanks. Using PHP to generate the chart options, so had to combine it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146075/how-to-output-javascript-date-in-json to get the Date.UTC to work. Found that v5.0.7 does not work out of the box: needed to download the master version from the link. Thanks again for the quick answer.